# Mixing floating text field with normal text field in one app. Bad design?

Tags: android, mobile-text-entry

In the app that I am designing, the user has to enter a verification code. Here I use a simple text field with a hint and no floating labels because there is no way to lose context of what you are doing. There is a line above of text above the text field reminding user of what they are entering.

In other place, where the user enters personal details like first and last name, I plan to use floating text fields. This is because the user may have to enter a lot of fields and it would be better to remind them of what they are doing.

However, does the mixing of floating text field and a normal one show bad design?

Should I just use one type of text field everywhere?

*Mockups:*

*Simple text field:*
[image]

*Floaty text field:*
[image]

Comment: Show a mockup please?

Comment: @luchomolina there you go! edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts:

1) Floating text fields (which I assume you mean the pattern where the label moves/slides up), help a lot in saving real estate, making the form cleaner, and **yet** giving context on what input the user is giving. So as we see, it solves a purpose. Not only focus retention as you mentioned.

2) In your case, its totally fine, if you are using them to simplify form entries.
And in case like a single input (verification code example) - you can surely go with a fixed form label.

3) You could do few things to maintain consistency:

- Have the same input field element design
- If possible, try placing the label (in verification scenario), the same way, as in once the label slides up (in your form design case).

4) Lets remember, helping a user fill the form or make an entry easily is the goal. If making it look beautiful/good is coming in the way, do not just judge by it.